# Why python script can't find device to cast

Tags: python-3.x, linux, chromecast

How cast on TV with package `pychromecast`, if this script can't find any chromecast? I installed it by guide [here](https://github.com/home-assistant-libs/pychromecast) and when i run this script I get an empty list.

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pychromecast
>>> chromecasts, browser = pychromecast.get_chromecasts()
>>> chromecasts
[]
```

I tried to type `catt scan` to terminal and it returned:

```
venv  username  username-Notebook-Type  ~  Path  To  Project  $  catt scan
Scanning Chromecasts...
Error: No devices found.
```

Then I set a static IP (192.168.1.8) to TV , also in router and run this script which returned me this error:

```
>>> import pychromecast
>>> cast = pychromecast.Chromecast('192.168.1.8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/patrik/Documents/Git/Home/Voice-Assistant/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pychromecast/__init__.py", line 328, in __init__
    raise ChromecastConnectionError(  # noqa
pychromecast.error.ChromecastConnectionError: Could not connect to 192.168.1.8:8009
```

I am able to cast via my mobile(youtube app) or Google Chrome(on laptop) to my TV.
I'm working in `venv`, but I also tried out of it.

I have laptop (Ubuntu) connected via ethernet cable to the same network as TV is (tried also through wi-fi). Python 3.8.5 with Pychromecast 7.7.1 installed via pip3. My tv is [Samsung Smart TV](https://www.samsung.com/sk/support/model/UE32K5672SUXXH/).